# ASP.NET MVC multi browser compabitibility issues?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, cross-browser

Does ASP.NET MVC4 has anything to do with multi-browser compatibility limitations?

In other words: the ASP.NET MVC engine also generates HTML server side which is displayed client side (right??), does it generate "non multi-browser compatible" HTML markup or do those two things have nothing to do with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC framework doesnt generate HTML by itself, it use view engines to create HTML like: RAZOR, ASPX, SPARK and etc.

Comment: Ok thx. And the razor, aspx, spark etc do they generate browser limiting html? Can i safely rely on razor or should i be very careful or write the html myself?

Comment: You write html by yourself. A view requests from the model the information that it needs to generate an output representation.

Answer (score 0):

No , asp.net MVC does not magically generate any html. it render wherever you put in your views.

you will have to write your code to be "multi-browser compatible".